# Have the non-async methods been removed from EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm playing around with writing some unit (ok, integration) tests, in C#, Xunit, and Sqlite.

Given that these are simply unit tests, I'd not planned to bother with dealing with the async methods. But when I tried:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

using (var dbContext = new TestDbContext(ContextOptions))
{
    var parent = dbContext.Parents.FirstOrDefault();
    parent.name.ShouldBe("Fred");
    }
}
```

I found that DbSet had no method "FirstOrDefault() or accessible extension method.

Of course, if I added a `using System.Linq;`, there was such a method defined.

But my worry - if `FirstOrDefault()` is implemented in System.Linq, and not in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, would that mean that all of the records would be retrieved, and then the first record extracted in memory?

This is far from what programmers would expect.

So the question, where did the non-async methods go?  `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` is in `public static class EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions`, but there are no non-async methods in it.

Have the async methods been removed?

Or are they in a different assembly?

Comment: Same issue. I'm only seeing SingleOrDefaultAsync().

Comment: It is implemented in `System.Linq`. Don't worry.

Comment: How could an implantation in System.Linq execute in the database?

Comment: Via `source.Provider.Execute`, check source of implementation. Actually if code uses Provider for execution, it means execution on the server side.

Comment: System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault() does not use source.Provider.

Comment: @JeffDege It's provided by the System.Linq.**Queryable** extensions methods. `Queryable` is quite different than `Enumerable`, even though the methods have one and the same names. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable-1?view=net-5.0

Comment: As mentioned by @IvanStoev, you have checked not right overload. Only `IQueryable` extensions have this possibility and only `IQueryable` has Provider property. Explaining everything will not fit into comments and even answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespace `System.Linq` has extension `Queryable.FirstOrDefault`. This extension builds Expression Tree, which includes `FirstOrDefault` method call. Expression Tree is passed to `IQueryable.Provider.Execute` method and then `IQueryProvider` generates SQL and provides all needed mappings.

This is standard behaviour and every LINQ providers uses this technique. Exception is `async` versions which are not included in standard and EF Core has to create it's own implementations.

Comment: So, if I include usings for both System.Linq and for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, and use queryable.FirstOrDefault(), it will execute on the database and return just the one record.

Thanks.